# Use generic class with graphql in .net core

Tags: c#, .net-core, graphql, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm new to [GraphQL](https://graphql.org), I'm making a small website which is for managing students and there classes.

In my application, I have a generic class:

```
public class RangeModel<TFrom, TTo>
    {
        #region Propertes

        public TFrom From { get; set; }

        public TTo To { get; set; }

        #endregion
    }
```

This class is for defining a range with generic data type.
Range can be:

`RangeModel<double?, double?>`

`RangeModel<int?, int?>`

... and so on.

I have tried making a `RangeModelType` class which inherits `ObjectGraphType` :

```
    public class RangeModelType<TFrom, TTo>: InputObjectGraphType<RangeModel<TFrom, TTo>>
        {
            public RangeModelType()
            {
                Field(x => x.From).Description("Minimum range");
                Field(x => x.To).Description("Maximum range");
            }
        }
```

And defined my query like below:

```
var studentsQueryArguments = new QueryArguments();
            studentsQueryArguments.Add(new QueryArgument<ListGraphType<IntGraphType>> { Name = "ids", Description = "Student indexes." });
            studentsQueryArguments.Add(new QueryArgument<ObjectGraphType<RangeModelType<double?, double?>>>{Name = "age", Description = "Age range of student."});
            Field<ListGraphType<StudentType>>(
                "students",
                arguments: studentsQueryArguments,
                resolve: context =>
                {
                    // Resolve data...
                    return results;
                });
        }
```

When I ran my app and did the query. One exception was thrown back which said:

> Unable to cast object of type GraphQL.Types.ObjectGraphType1[GraphQlStudy.Models.GraphQL.Types.RangeModelType2[System.Nullable1[System.Double],System.Nullable1[System.Double]]]' to type 'GraphQL.Types.ScalarGraphType'.

I have been searching for tutorials that use GraphQL and generic class, but nothing mentions about using this kind of Generic class.

Can anyone help me ?

Thanks,

Comment: i don't know too much about graphQL, but this looks like ObjectGraphType and ScalarGraphType are incompatible, independent of generics... you could verify that by using a simpler objectgraphtype.

Answer (score 6):

After having spent hours, I have the following solution.

1. Define `RangeModel.cs` as:

   ```
   public class RangeModel<TFrom, TTo>
   {
       public TFrom From { get; set; }

       public TTo To { get; set; }
   }
   ```
2. Define `RangeModelType.cs`:

   ```
   public class RangeModelType<TFrom, TTo> : InputObjectGraphType<RangeModel<TFrom, TTo>>
   {
       public RangeModelType()
       {
           var fromType = typeof(TFrom);
           Field(x => x.From, fromType.IsGenericType && fromType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>));

           var toType = typeof(TTo);
           Field(x => x.To, toType.IsGenericType && toType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>));
       }
   }
   ```
3. This is my query argument:

   ```
   studentsQueryArguments.Add(new QueryArgument<RangeModelType<double?, double?>> {Name = "age", Description = "Age range of student."});
   ```

I don't know whether this implementation is good or not. For now, it solves my problem.

Hope this help.